# Tools for visualising execution xml plans as HTML

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

Are there any tools / XSLT style sheets around for transforming the XML execution plans returned by Microsoft Visual Studio into HTML?

Failing that, does anyone know of any techniques that can be used to display charts in HTML suitable for displaying execution plans?

Comment: +1 If there are, I'd like to know!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I couldn't find one so I made one myself

https://github.com/JustinPealing/html-query-plan

[image: Screenshot]

Its currently being used on the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and Azure Data Studio.

Comment: [Any input to this question?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14727/interpreting-sql-servers-showplan-xml)

Comment: This is very nice. Would be even better there was a ZIP file to be downloaded that contained all the necessary files.